# Why is res.json() returning null?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, routes, jwt

I'm trying to code the authentification part of my react app using jwt. I kept getting this error in my App.js file: 'Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'error')', which led me to find out that when a certain route is accessed, which should return some data about the user, the response body is actually empty. These are some snippets of my code, where I think the problem might be. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance! Also, please let me know if I should provide other snippets of code

This is from my App.js file

```
const [authState, setAuthState] = useState({
    username: "", 
    id: 0, 
    status: false,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:3001/users/auth", {
        headers: {
          accessToken: localStorage.getItem("accessToken"),
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data.error) { //this is where the error appears
          setAuthState({ ...authState, status: false });
        } else {
          setAuthState({
            username: response.data.username, //if I comment the line where the error appears, I get the same error here and on the line below, but with 'username' and 'id' instead of 'error'
            id: response.data.id,
            status: true,
          });
        }
      });
  }, []);
```

This is where res.json doesn't return anything

```
router.get('/auth', validateToken, (req, res) => {
    res.json(req.user);
});
```

This is the validateToken middleware

```
const { verify } = require('jsonwebtoken');

const validateToken = (req, res, next) => {
    const accessToken = req.header("accessToken");

    if (!accessToken) return res.json({ error: "User not logged in!" })

    try {
        const validToken = verify(accessToken, "importantsecret");
        req.user = validToken; //we can access the username and id
        if (validToken) {
            return next();
        }
    } catch (err) {
        return res.json({ error: err });
    }
};

module.exports = { validateToken };
```

Comment: Shouldn't route.get be "/users/auth" instead of just "/auth"?

Comment: from AXIOS you GET `/users/auth`;  but your route seems to be `/auth`

Comment: It s not this, because in index.js, where I declared the routers, I have this:                 const usersRouter = require("./routes/Users");
app.use("/users", usersRouter);

Comment: So you get data when you console.log(res) in your router.get ?

Comment: @SeanLawton If I add a console.log(response) right before the line where I get the error, in App.js, I get [object Object]. If I add it in the router.get request, I nothing shows up in my console

Comment: that means you're not hitting the route

Comment: @GrafiCode And do you have any idea of what to change or add in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so in your middleware function, in this particular line,

```js
const validToken = verify(accessToken, "importantsecret");
req.user = validToken; //we can access the username and id
if (validToken) {
     return next();
}
```

Here, you are creating a constant variable named "validToken" and setting req.user to it. And then, you are checking if it exists, then run next(), but what if validToken is null/undefined? next() is never ran then!

Comment: It does, I just added it in the post. Maybe it isn't called in the right place?

Comment: Okay, I get what you mean. I tried to write an if statement for the null/undefined cases, but nothing changes, it doesn't seem to go on that branch

Answer (score -2):

Maybe it's because you literally don't return your response.

Try this one.

`router.get('/auth', validateToken, (req, res) => { return res.json(req.user); });`

Comment: I get the same result, even if I add the return